# How to discard an invocation in GLSL compute shader

Tags: opengl, glsl, compute-shader

I'm trying to implement forward+ rendering using compute shaders in GLSL 4.6, but I don't know how to synchronize threads within a work group when working with off-screen pixels. For example, my window resolution is `1600x900`, and I'm using a work group size of `16x16`, where each thread or invocation corresponds to a single pixel on the screen, this means that `size_x = 1600/16 = 100` and `size_y = 900/16 = 56.25`, so I need to call

```cpp
glDispatchCompute(100, 57, 1);
```

As you can see, some threads in a work group may represent pixels that extend beyond the screen, so I want to `return` early or `discard` these off-screen pixels to skip the complex computation. However, my compute shader also contains a `barrier()` call in several places in order to synchronize local threads, I don't know how to combine them. The documentation says

> For any given static instance of barrier in a compute shader, all invocations within a single work group must enter it before any are allowed to continue beyond it.
>
> ......
>
> Barriers are also disallowed after a return statement

The only workaround I can think of is to fake computations for these threads, or use `if-else` to let them finish early in an intermediate stage between two `barrier()` calls. I guess this will introduce a little performance penalty. So, is there a better way to rule out invalid threads in a work group? I believe this problem is quite common for compute shaders so there might be an idiomatic way of handling it.

Comment: "*so I want to return early or discard these off-screen pixels to skip the complex computation*" Even if you could, it's probably not going to save you anything. "*I believe this problem is quite common for compute shaders*" No, it's not. Most people don't write forward renderers in CS's because that's horribly inefficient.

Comment: @NicolBolas, it's the tiled forward renderer, not the default forward renderer, the original paper did it in compute shaders so I tried the same. But you're right, return early won't have any performance gains since a single thread have to wait other threads anyway, I guess I should just flag them as invalid and discard the result at the end of the main function.

Comment: Not all threads in a work group run simultaneously, therefore skipping the computation between the barriers *may* improve performance. However, this will save, at best, 1.3% for the numbers in question; and is likely to cost you more for the additional conditionals that will need to be checked even in the 98% of work groups that don't fall on the edge.